# using gecoder in subscribe angular 2

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-geocoder

hi i want to reserve geocode from langitude and longitude from json data to address name

### my component ts

```
     getAllMap() {
    this.mapLocationService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        ml => {
          this.maplocations = ml;
          let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.maplocations['map_location_latitude'], this.maplocations['map_location_longitude']); // <- problem when i call init google map
          console.log(latlng);
          let request = latlng;
          let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              console.log('status' + status);
              if (results[0] != null) {
                this.city = results[0].address_components[results[0].address_components.length - 4].short_name;
                console.log('city' + this.city);
              } else {
                this.city = 'No address available';
              }
            }
          });
        },
        error => {
          this.errorMessage = error;
        }
      );
  }
```

### already include in import and install

```
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
declare var google: any;
```

so the problem always showing error

> ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import { } from 'googlemaps';
```

instead of

```
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
declare var google: any;
```